# Have Apache ignore requests when Host header is not right

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I would like Apache 2.4.x to ignore (i.e., not respond to) any request that does not match a specific domain name. My configuration is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName foobar.com
 RedirectMatch /(.*) https://www.foobar.com/$1
 ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.foobar.com

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Are the ServerName fields sufficient to instruct Apache to not respond to requests not matching any of my ServerName values in my VirtualHosts?

The way I would like Apache to behave is to look at the Host request header, compare it to the ServerName fields above, and ignore requests whose Host header value does not match anything.

My site is https-only and port 80 is not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will always be *some* answer, as a connection has to be established in order to see the host header.

As you're https only, odds are that certificate negotiation will fail for unknown or unconfigured domains.

In general, you should configure a virtual host for all known domains and fall back to the default virtual host for any requests that don't match.

Clients *will* see a certificate error, there's nothing you can do against that. But you're in control of the message that is shown to all clients that either don't get a certificate error or choose to connect nevertheless. You do that by explicitly configuring the *default* virtual host accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, in this case I will return (at the application level) a 400 Bad Request error for improper host requests. (BTW, https-only certificate negotiation should be fine as long as I configure the challenge to use DNS-01, not HTTP-01 ; DNS-01 does not use http and port 80).

Comment: Forget about the challenge, I got your point...

Answer (score 0):

Use a '[require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)' directive.

```
Require %{HTTP_HOST} -strcmatch 'foobar.com'
```

that will return http status 403 (Forbidden) if host doesn't match